# Site themes; how would I make this extract of code work?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I need to know how to make this work. I removed one of the less than signs due to it hiding the code.:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\CSS\stylesheet2.css" />
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do? Are you putting a `<link>` inside of a `<script>`?

Comment: No I'm trying to make themes, so say if they chose, say theme 3, it'd choose a different CSS doc. Before I code that I want to know I can make it choose a different CSS doc with JS, since HTML doesn't allow for if statements.

Comment: I'll be using cookies to store which one they chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean, but if you want to load the stylesheet from javascript you would do like this:

```
function load()
{        
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = "style/style.css";
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";

    head.appendChild(link);
}
window.onload = load;
```

If you want something conditional, you can implement that into the code

Comment: Thanks :) Much appreciated. This site is prety fast response wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


if(yourBoolean1) {

var newSS=document.createElement('link');

newSS.rel='stylesheet';

newSS.href='data:text/css,'+escape(styles);

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newSS);

}


</script>
```

Comment: I need it to have a conditional statement. There'll be multiple CSS docs.

Comment: Do you have to do it using javascript?  Can the site do any pre-processing like php or asp?

Comment: I cannot grasp the concepts of ASP and I'd have to learn a whole new language for PHP. Is there no way of using JS?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be with a server-side script like PHP, so the desired theme will be loaded from the start. This also makes cookie handling a lot easier.

Failing that, you would need to read `document.cookie` and find the value, then bring it in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.cookie;
    if( c.indexOf("theme")>-1) {
        c = c.split(";");
        while(c[0].indexOf("theme")==-1) c.shift();
        c = c[0]; // we now have the part of the cookie with the theme
        c = c.split("=")[1]; // this is the value of said cookie
        var l = document.createElement('link');
        l.type = 'text/css';
        l.rel = 'stylesheet';
        l.src = '..\CSS\stylesheet'+c+'.css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(l);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'll be cooki-(ing?) an integer so that I won't need a complicated process, thanks for helping though :)

Comment: I wrote this with the assumption that you'd be setting the cookie as an integer. The above will (should) work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, that'd be me. I suck at the more complicated attributes of almost all site languages. I preffer realy well set API's. I'll try using this and see if it works. :). Thanks